# How do you create a folder using the command line?

Tags: mac, command-line

How do you create a new folder / directory using the command line?

Comment: Have you done any research before asking this question? Please see [ask] for a few tips.

Comment: A bit, but figured that two google searches and a search on superuser didn't yield ultra clear post merited another.

Comment: How can you Google for something like that even once (let alone twice) and not find the answer? 4 words: "create folder command line"!

Comment: -1 This question shows absolutely zero research effort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the command

```
mkdir newdirname
```

Answer (score 2):

`md <directoryname>` is also a shorter syntax of mkdir